# How to use Sylius as back-end? Its REST APIs are only for admin users

Tags: sylius

I have read sylius document about REST API. I found that all the REST APIs of Sylius are used for admin user, so I cannot separate front-end with back-end.[Same question like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47836453/is-sylius-api-production-ready/48274538)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ShopApi plugin to have full experience of Sylius APIs :) https://github.com/Sylius/SyliusShopApiPlugin

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have tried this plugin, but it does not suitable for me.